# Options is coming instead of put

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ajax

This is the front-end part

```
$scope.result = {};

$scope.edit = function() {
  console.log($scope.result); //This is working
  $http.put('http://localhost:4000/customer/' + $routeParams.id, $scope.result)
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.result = data;
      console.log("posted successfully") //This is not working
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Catching at `.catch` every time

Answer (score 0):

`OPTIONS` calls are generally made on their own to check if an API allows CORS for requests coming in from a particular domain.

I'm pretty sure what's happening here is, when you're making the `PUT` call, `$http` is first making the `OPTIONS` call to see if the API supports `CORS`. But since it doesn't, it's returning an Error. This error is getting caught in your `.catch` block.

If this was a GET request, you could have used `JSONP` instead of `GET`(considering the API supported `JSONP` requests).

But since this is not, you can do two things here:

1. Get your Domain whitelisted on the API if you have a control on the API.
2. Create a proxy which will relay your request to that API. Since this proxy will be treated as a server and not a client, and since CORS is only a browser-based policy, your request will go through successfully.

Hope this makes sense.